# SQL CLR Exception when trying to convert PDF

Tags: c#, sql, pdf, clr

I'm using a third party component within my CLR component (2.0)
Everything is working until I get to the part where I try to use the 3rd party component to do a conversion..

```
htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(htmlPath);
```

The following error occurs.

> System.Exception: Could not start conversion. Could not get the
>   assembly code base. Full Trust level is required. Check the 'trust'
>   section in the configuration file. Check if the assembly was blocked
>   by OS and use Unblock button in file properties to enable it and
>   restart IIS worker process.

I have unblocked the assembly, granted full trust through the .net configuration tool (all related assemblies) & set the permission to unsafe.

The component has a .dat helper file & .xml file. Not sure how these can be granted permissions & am unsure if this may be the root of the issue.  They reside in the same folder.  Everything works in my console test app.  Just when implemented through SQL is the problem.

Not sure what else to try.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This answer to a similar question might be of interest: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42854

Comment: have you checked which User is used to run the code? It would be worth to check it and try to run the Console app under the same user to see if this issue is related to the User permissions.